# Hibernate Query auto Flush

Tags: hibernate

we have just made a massive upgrade for our web application - jumped from jboss 4 to jboss 7.
we have also moved from hibernate 3 to hibernate 4.

I have encountered this weird behavior (which did not happen under hibernate 3):
1. I run an hql (lets say the hql filters the status field - status = 1) and get one object back.
2. I change its status to 2.
3. I run the hql again and get the same object (its even the same instance - with the changed status!) - which does not match the criteria anymore!

I found out that the problem is that the session is not flushed automatically before the query, this is weird because the session has flushmode.auto.

can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the transaction factory class (property name - hibernate.transaction.factory_class). It basically comes down to the fact that in a JTA scenario with the JtaTransactionFactory configured, hibernate does not detect that it is in a transaction and will therefore not execute intermediate flushes. when changing it to org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory, everything works.

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the flush mode explicitly to a appropriate value, other modes are available.

```
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);
```

Also, can flush manually `session.flush()`

From Documentation :

> - **ALWAYS :** The Session is flushed before every query.
> - **AUTO :** The Session is ***sometimes*** flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state.

(emphasis from my part)

---

**Edit :** I haven't tried it applying at application level, but you can specify it in persistence.xml

```
<property name="org.hibernate.FlushMode" value="always" />
```

And in hibernate.cfg.xml as

```
<property name="hibernate.flushMode">ALWAYS</property>
```

Comment: it seems it is ignored!
I mean the flush mode is always, but hibernate still does not flush the data.

Comment: @user1960555 Before query, have you tried `session.flush()` & ensure it doesn't pick from cache.

Comment: yes, manually flushing works..
but I want it to flush automatically.
I did see that the presistenceContext inside the session has a property called flushing which is false, do you know what this means?

Comment: @user1960555 They are vendor specific properties for the persistence provider. Also you can try to mention this property while creating session factory.

Comment: what property are you talking about?

Comment: in any case, auto and normal modes don't help.
do you have another idea?

Comment: I found the problem, it was the transaction factory class (property name - hibernate.transaction.factory_class).

It basically comes down to the fact that in a JTA scenario with the JtaTransactionFactory configured, hibernate does not detect that it is in a transaction and will therefore not execute intermediate flushes.

when changing it to org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory, everything works.

Comment: @user1960555 You can add it as an answer, might help someone with similar issue.